# Dollar sign plus in Perl?

Tags: perl

I came across the following and I'm unsure what it means:

```
$+{decimal}
```

I'm familiar with the use of `$` in Perl, but haven't seen it followed by a plus sign before.

*The word decimal hasn't been defined anywhere in the script.*

Can someone explain the syntax of `$+{ }`?

Answer (score 5):

Check for `%+` hash variable in [perlvar](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%25%2b)

> Similar to `@+` , the `%+` hash allows access to the named capture buffers, should they exist, in the last successful match in the currently active dynamic scope.
>
> For example, `$+{foo}` is equivalent to `$1` after the following match:

```
'foo' =~ /(?<foo>foo)/;
```

Comment: Realizing you copied and pasted from the docs, I think the example leads to  confusion, since `foo` is used for the string, the pattern, and the named capture variable.  The example would do better to differentiate where `$+{foo}` originates from w/in the example, which I believe is the `<foo>` portion.

Comment: It seems like docs would benefit from some improvements.

Comment: Yes most likely the string and the pattern just need to use `bar` (unless my understanding is wrong, which is entirely possible, since I've never used named capture variables, nor tested the example.